# Flutter: How to get User ID from Firebase Authentication when Sign in with Apple or Google

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I recently added the "Sign in with Apple" and "Sign In with Google" Function to my app. When Users in the past registered with Email and Password a document for each user was created with the user Id as the name of the document.

I need to get the User ID like in the User-DataTable in Firebase like shown in the picture below:
[image: Screenshot]

My Code for Signing in with Apple:
*Instead of gUser.id I need the UID from Firebase*

```
signInWithApple() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    try {
      final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
        nonce: nonce
      );

      final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
        idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
        rawNonce: rawNonce,
      );

      //*Create User Doc
      final doc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(oauthCredential.idToken);

      final parkbestUser = ParkbestUser(
        email: appleCredential.email.toString(),
        uid: appleCredential.userIdentifier.toString(),
        creationTime: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        isController: false,
        controllCity: "",
        signInMethod: "apple.com",
      );

      final json = parkbestUser.toJson();

      try {
        await doc.set(json);
        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }

      final authResult =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

      final displayName =
          '${appleCredential.givenName} ${appleCredential.familyName}';
      final userEmail = '${appleCredential.email}';

      final firebaseUser = authResult.user;
      print(displayName);
      await firebaseUser!.updatePhotoURL("");
      await firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(displayName);
      await firebaseUser.updateEmail(userEmail);

      return firebaseUser;
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

My Code for Signing in with Google:
*Instead of gUser.id I need the UID from Firebase*

When using gUser.id I get an Id which contains only numbers and is shorter than the typical UID

```
signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: gAuth.idToken,
    );

    //*Create User Doc
    final userDoc =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(gUser.id);

    final parkbestUser = ParkbestUser(
      email: gUser.email,
      uid: gUser.id,
      creationTime: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      isController: false,
      controllCity: "",
      signInMethod: credential.signInMethod,
    );

    final json = parkbestUser.toJson();

    try {
      await userDoc.get().then((doc) {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          userDoc.set(json);
        } else {}
      });
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      print("------------------- - - - - - - - - - $e");
    }
  }
```

**My Question:**
How do I get the UID (User Id) from Firebase to add it to the Document for each User?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you checked `authResult.user.uid`?

Comment: You can use this as reference [Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users)